# Stream edited images of PiCam to Youtube using Python

Tags: python, opencv, youtube, streaming

I'm working on project were I have a Raspberry Pi (Running Raspbian Jessie) with a camera (PiCam or a USB webcam) and I want to stream the images from the cam to Youtube and edit the images in realtime using OpenCV (add text and a logo) but I just can't figure it out. The fact that I'm a novice in Unix and Python doesn't help either.

I am able to edit each frame of the video stream using the following python code

```
import cv2, sys
import time

capture = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 1280)
capture.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 720)

while True:
  rc, img = capture.read()
  if not rc:
    continue

  #make a copy of the image to add the semi-transparant bar
  overlay = img.copy()
  cv2.rectangle(overlay, (0,700), (1280, 720), (1,1,1),-1)
  cv2.addWeighted(overlay, 0.75, img, 0.25, 0, img)

  #add the text
  imageText = "[{}]".format(time.strftime("%d %b %Y %H:%M:%S", time.localtime()))
  cv2.putText(img, imageText, (10, 713), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.4,(255,255,255))
```

But now I have to add these frames to a output stream and send it to the rtmp stream of Youtube in the right format. I've been searching the internet and documentation all day but I can't seem to find a answer that does the job. I really can't see the wood for the trees...

Has anybody got a solution or can point me in the right direction.